# How to code a PtEngine/Google Analytics clone in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I've been looking for any kind of starting tutorial on how to code an Analytics type web app in Ruby on Rails and Javascript.

I know that those sites require some kind of javascript code that gets inserted on each page of the site and some kind of server side program, but are there any existing tutorials that anyone knows of where I could learn more about how to get started in that area?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the Google Analytics API [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/analytics/v3).

Also look at the google-analytics-rails gem [link](https://github.com/bgarret/google-analytics-rails).